# javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpRequest error

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, servlets

I get this error when my `Servlet` is invoked. However, I **do** have `httpclient-4.5.7.jar` file in my `WEB-INF/lib` folder. What else does tomcat wants from me?

**EDIT:**

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpRequest
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    com.web.RedditUserInfo.doPost(RedditUserInfo.java:45)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpRequest
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:916)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:845)
    org.apache.jsp.user_005fview_jsp._jspService(user_005fview_jsp.java:319)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    com.web.RedditUserInfo.doPost(RedditUserInfo.java:45)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpRequest
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2957)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    main.RedditParser.getAccessToken(RedditParser.java:61)
    main.RedditParser.<init>(RedditParser.java:43)
    org.apache.jsp.user_005fview_jsp._jspService(user_005fview_jsp.java:166)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    com.web.RedditUserInfo.doPost(RedditUserInfo.java:45)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.HttpRequest
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2957)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    main.RedditParser.getAccessToken(RedditParser.java:61)
    main.RedditParser.<init>(RedditParser.java:43)
    org.apache.jsp.user_005fview_jsp._jspService(user_005fview_jsp.java:166)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    com.web.RedditUserInfo.doPost(RedditUserInfo.java:45)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

**EDIT:**

I added `httpcore-4.2.1.jar`, and now I get the:

`javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/config/Lookup` error..

Comment: Don't know what Tomcat wants from you, but we want to see the full stacktrace, so please **edit** the question and show it.

Comment: Did you include the `httpcore-4.4.11.jar` too? That's where the `org.apache.http.HttpRequest` class is.

Comment: @Andreas Added `httpcore-4.4.11.jar` and get a `javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory` error. Apache libs are a joke ;(

Comment: They are not a joke. It's up to you to include all dependent jar files. If you used a build tool with dependency management, like Maven or Gradle, it would all be taken care of for you.